# Ancient Chinese method to calculating $\pi$

Tags: pythagorean-proposition

I'm trying to understand the following passage from Boyer's and Merzbach's [History of Mathematics](https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema00boye):

[image: page 203]

[image: Fig. 9.1]

The question I have is: how does the author derive that $w^2=2rv$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R'$ be the reflection of $R$ on $O$ (see the picture below). Then $RR'$ is a diameter of the circle and therefore its length is $2r$.

The triangles $\triangle RQR'$ and $\triangle RMQ$ are similar, since both of them are right triangles and $\angle Q\hat RM=\angle Q\hat RR'$. So,$$\frac{\overline{RM}}{\overline{RQ}}=\frac{\overline{RQ}}{\overline{RR'}},$$but$$\frac{\overline{RM}}{\overline{RQ}}=\frac{\overline{RQ}}{\overline{RR'}}\iff\frac vw=\frac w{2r}\iff w^2=2rv.$$

[image]